# Showing how one definition of div follows from another

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how can I do a formal proof of the following description:

$a\;div\;b =
\begin{cases}
\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor &\text{ if }b>0\\
\lceil \frac{a}{b} \rceil &\text{ if }b<0
\end{cases}\\$

It seems pretty straight forward as $a$ div $b$ is defined as $q$ from the expression $a=q b + r$, where r has to be a positive integer smaller than b.

Comment: I believe is $a=qb+r$ with $0\leq r<b$ positive integer.

Comment: Just use the definition of the floor function.

Comment: Thank you @Pambos; you're right.
@Adeel - well I know what floor and ceil functions do, but even then it seems trivial that q has to be largest integer not greater than the quotient (if b>0) and the otherway around for b<0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b\mid a$ is easy. So assume that $b\nmid a$.

Let $k$ be the largest integer that is smaller to $\dfrac{a}{b}$, i.e. $k$ is the integer with the property $k<\dfrac{a}{b}<k+1$. 
If $b>0$ then for $0<s=\dfrac{a}{b}-k<1$ we have $a=kb+sb$ and $0
<sb<b$. Therefore $a \text{ div } b=k=\lfloor\dfrac{a}{b}\rfloor$.
If $b<0$ then for $0<s=k+1-\dfrac{a}{b}<1$ we have $a=(k+1)b-sb$ and $0
<-sb<b$. Therefore $a \text{ div } b=k+1=\lceil\dfrac{a}{b}\rceil$.